# Remote debugging eclipse via jump host

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, host

I have a tomcat running on a server which can only be accessed via a jump host. We can enable remote debugging in eclipse if we can access the server directly (like the jump host). I was wondering is there any way that I can remote debug the tomcat which is running on a server which can't be directly accessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your infrastructure correctly I can think of 2 possible ways to do this.

1. Port forward some of the jump host's ports (8000 for example) to debug port of your tomcat server. Then start remote debugging in eclipse as you would normally do (i.e. "Socket Attach" to jump host ip and port 8000).
2. If you can reach host with running eclipse instance from your server (the one that runs tomcat) - you can make tomcat connect to your eclipse that uses "Socket Listen" remote debugging mode.

Comment: Can you help me with port forwarding. All the 3 servers are Linux based.

Comment: @Anshul There are more than one way to configure port forwarding, here is a nice tutorial showing one of them: http://www.ridinglinux.org/2008/05/21/simple-port-forwarding-with-iptables-in-linux/ Notify me if it won't work for you for any reason.

Comment: I was able forward the port. But just to find out that my code is so huge that it won't run in debug mode on local machine. :(

Comment: @Anshul Hmmm, interesting. Just out of curiosity - how does it look like? I mean, debug takes too long or eclipse telling you something?

Comment: It has almost 40K classes and 2.5K packages :D. My eclipse hangs at 22-24% while launching and throws GC overhead limit exceeded after some time. And says "An internal error occurred while showing an internal error." :D

Comment: @Anshul hehe, seems like quite a big project :) BTW, have you tried to increase your eclipse permgen/heap size? This might help if you reached jvm memory limits but not os limits.

Comment: @ Eugeny yeah, I've tried that already with 4gb. All my colleagues are  struggling with same. we've to push our class files to a different server with log statements in order to debug it. :)